# Javascript rich text editor, how to know if text to be typed will be bold?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have simple javascript rich text editor consiting only of bold button that has following onclick:

```
  document.execCommand('bold', false)
```

And simple html...

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

How do I know, if text that I type is going to be bold for real? I could track button if it's clicked, but when the cursor moves, I paste something, etc...

I need something like "isBold" function to get the button UI that is saying it is applied.

Comment: `contenteditable` is something everyone discovers and thinking it's so awesome but later comes to realize that it's just the opposite and wish they just have just gone with a wysiwyg editor

Comment: I think you meant *wish

Comment: @Endless But isn't a contenteditable a wysiwyg editor as it is, or do you mean it is a wysiwywg editor (what you see is what you won't get)?

Comment: You get little control over the contenteditable and it behaves differently in browser where new lines can differ between `\n` and `<br>`... When I mean a wysiwyg editor then i mean something like this: [Froala Editor](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor). ofc there is many other alternativs out there that can be more suitable for anuglar/vue/react

Comment: Froala seems to lean on `contenteditable` as well ...

Comment: So I have came to solutions, that I have to parse HTML trought javascript to see if something is inside the tag, and then see if to-be-typed content will be bold or not...